# Sipp - Run Custom Scenario At Server

Tags: asterisk, sip

To Run sipp with embedded server (uas) scenario: 
[ http://sipp.sourceforge.net/index.html ]

> sipp -sn uas

The problem is that  I want to run  a specific scenario on server such that :

1. Server will accept call,
2. Then play a music. [ Suppose for 30 secons ]
3. Finally  will hangup call

If possible

> How can I run this specific scenario on server with Sipp tool ?

**Maybe will be usefull for others:**

I find a good scenario repo at https://github.com/saghul/sipp-scenarios

And scenario sipp_uas_pcap_g711a.xml seems a good candidate for my purposes.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saghul/sipp-scenarios/master/sipp_uas_pcap_g711a.xml

When you invoke a custom scenario  use this command

> sipp -i 10.10.10.24 -sf  sipp_uas_pcap.xml

Info:

> 10.10.10.24 is local ip, sipp_uas_pcap.xml is scenario file name. Becareful while setting pcap file path at the scenario
>   sipp_uas_pcap.xml

Comment: As i read on your given URL, "SIPp is a free Open Source test tool / traffic generator for the SIP protocol." , Yes,U can test this scenario. You just have  to right dialplan for  the server.

Comment: Thanks... I find samples scenarious at https://github.com/saghul/sipp-scenarios and sipp_uas_pcap_g711a.xml seems the right dial plan.